# HTML5 web app, define routes via JSON, PHP or dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, single-page-application

I'm working on an HTML5 web app (with no specific MVC framework). I'm unsure how to define all possible routings.

Currently, I do it on the fly once any URL gets hit:

If a user calls `domain.com/test` the app will create a `new Page('test')`. The `Page` constructor will then get a handlebars template, create the view ect ect. This is done once (first visit of `/test`). On every subsequent visit, the already available view is inserted into the DOM.

This is obviously flawed, as visits to `domain.com/thispagedoesntexist` or any other URL that isn't available (as in, there is no handlebars template) will still create a `Page` object.

To fix this, I need predefined routings, correct? This means I need to define which pages, routes and templates are available in the first place (all others get a 404 then). Is there a right way to do that?

The only way that comes to my mind is to create a JSON file, JS object or PHP array with all the routes defined:

```
var routes = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        slug: '/home',
        template: 'pages/home.hbs'
    },
    {
        title: 'Imprint',
        slug: '/imprint',
        template: 'pages/imprint.hbs'
    },
    {
        title: 'About us',
        slug: '/about',
        template: 'pages/about.hbs'
    }
];
```

and then match the current visited URL. If it isn't in this array, I'll return the 404 page.

Is this the way to do it? I'm not sure if there is THE right way and I'm sorry if I'm asking for best practises right now.

Let's ask it this way: what's the generally recommended way to define routes in an single-page web app?

If the way I posted above is actually the correct way to do it, is there a security risk of using it in a JSON or JS file, or should I rather do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a big question and it brings another one : will you have permission for each page and how will you manage them ?

Then, as far as you build a single page app, php routes can't be used.

At last, I would say that there's a lot of solutions available like [page.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) or [crossroads](http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/) you could use. Or do you need to do it yourself?

Comment: I *want* to do it myself - to understand how it's done. I didn't mean to use PHP routes, just to save the array in there and ask for it via AJAX. I don't need permissions. All these pages are public.